# Color T2I adapter for Stable Diffusion XL?

Tags: stable-diffusion

I've been using [T2I-Adapters](https://github.com/TencentARC/T2I-Adapter) with Stable Diffusion XL via ComfyUI.

There are couple of adapters that Tencent has [published](https://github.com/TencentARC/T2I-Adapter/blob/SD/docs/AdapterZoo.md) only for SD1.4, but not (as far as I can tell) for SDXL. I'm specifically interested in using the [color adapter](https://github.com/TencentARC/T2I-Adapter/blob/SD/docs/examples.md#color-adapter-spatial-palette) with SDXL.

Do I just have to wait and hope they eventually publish one, or are there comparable / compatible projects that work in the same way? In particular I prefer T2I adapters over ControlNet for performance reasons.